# Generating Hashes using .NET Core

Tags: security, random, hash, .net-core

I need to Generate Random Unique hashes to be used in password reset links in .Net Core. In ASP.NET Identity, I found this to be helpful, I am wondering if *RNGCryptoServiceProvider* still assures the randomness of the hashes generated.

```
 using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                var data = new byte[4];
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    //filled with an array of random numbers
                    rngCsp.GetBytes(data);
                    //this is converted into a character from A to Z
                    var randomchar = Convert.ToChar(
                        //produce a random number 
                        //between 0 and 25
                        BitConverter.ToUInt32(data, 0) % 26
                        //Convert.ToInt32('A')==65
                                              + 65
                    );
                    token.Append(randomchar);
                }
            }
```

What is the best way to achieve that using .net core and using which classes?

Comment: As a side note, `% 26` means you won't have a even distribution of your random data, so your random generator will currently prefer some letters over others.

Comment: By the way, the tokens are strictly speaking not "hashes", since it's just a random sequence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is not in .NET Core. Use `RandomNumberGenerator.Create()` to get an instance of a CSPRNG that will work on the correct platform. Its API is the same as `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`, except that `GetNonZeroBytes` is missing (which I'd argue shouldn't have even been there).

On Windows, this will boil down to `BCryptGenRandom` in CNG, and on Linux it will use OpenSSL.